# Model of homotopy type theory in ZFC

Tags: set-theory, foundations, homotopy-type-theory

There is a model of ZFC in homotopy type theory

Does exist a model of homotopy type theory in ZFC?

Is there a proof of "equal logical expressivity" of these theories?

p.s. I use word "model" in common sense, because I don't know model theory

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Yes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.2851), as long as by "ZFC" you include its extension with some inaccessible cardinals, or (perhaps) are willing to play games with natural models.  In other words, the only difference in consistency strength is that "ZFC" by default doesn't include any universes, while "HoTT" by default includes countably many.

Comment: I'm confused - doesn't this require 2 inaccessibles? (Or am I not parsing it right?)

Comment: The correct answer is "No", Mike, and your link indicates that. You may want to clarify what you mean. (Of course, the answer is "yes" if $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is replaced with one of its standard extensions via large cardinals, but that seems to be precisely the point of the question.)

Comment: It was not at all obvious to me that that is the point of the question, but I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: Countably many with only two inaccessible cardinals?

Comment: @AsafKaragila The universes here are not Grothendieck universes. The model is built starting from two Grothendieck universes. It has strength beyond $\mathsf{ZFC}$ because you can interpret set theory inside.

Comment: @Andrés: I know, of course, that inaccessible cardinals exceed ZFC, I was surprised you only need two.

Comment: You need countably many inaccessibles if you want to model a HoTT that has countably many universes.  The paper that I linked to uses two inaccessibles to construct a model of a HoTT with one universe.