# What is the proof theoretic ordinal of Homotopy Type theory?

Tags: ordinals, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory, ordinal-analysis

The proof theoretic ordinal of Martin-Löf type theory is $\Gamma_0$.

What about HoTT and what about other flavors of type theory (the ones related to the lambda cube for instance)?

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is unknown: current ordinal analysis only gets up to around $\Pi^1_2$-$\mathsf{CA_0}$, and my recollection is that HoTT is vastly stronger than that - around the level of [ZFC + two inaccessibles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1588578/model-of-homotopy-type-theory-in-zfc). It's almost impossible to describe how vast the gulf between subsystems of second-order arithmetic and ZFC is; I would be profoundly surprised if the proof-theoretic ordinal of anything near ZFC was computed in my lifetime.

As to much weaker type theories, [these slides of Buchholtz](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506124046/https://www2.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/%7Ebuchholtz/bielefeld-proof-theory.pdf) and [this paper of Setzer](https://journals.openedition.org/msh/pdf/2959) have some relevant information. But again, unless my understanding is wildly off-base any variant of HoTT with around the same power is going to be far out of reach of current ordinal analysis.

Comment: You only need the power of ZFC+Inaccessibles if your version of HoTT is classical. You can construct cubical models without LEM in much weaker theories. The Buchholtz slides you link to even make these claims.

Comment: [This paper of Rathjen's](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02191) claims adding univaence to MLTT doesn't change the strength.

Comment: More precisely, I believe it's not classical logic but rather impredicativity that blows up the proof-theoretic strength.  I don't entirely understand Rathjen's argument or the calculation of the proof-theoretic ordinal of MLTT, but I believe it relies crucially on predicativity.  Including the impredicativity axiom that the book calls "propositional resizing" is, I believe, sufficient to prove equiconsistency with IZF + inaccessibles, which is in turn equiconsistent with ZFC + inaccessibles.

Comment: @MikeShulman Does HoTT include propositional resizing by default?

Comment: "HoTT" is the name of the entire subject, not of a particular formal system.  "Book HoTT" refers to the formal system used in the HoTT Book, but is imprecise among other reasons because it's ambiguous about whether axioms like propositional resizing are included.  So I would say that probably there is no "default", but others might disagree.